# For all integers a and b if $a|b$ then $a^2|3b^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For all integers a and b if $a|b$ then $a^2|3b^2$

my attempt: As $a|b$ then exists a integer $k$ such that $b=ka$ then $a^2=k^2b^2$ this means that $a^2|b^2$ but i cant go for further

Comment: I suggest using $\mid$ and $\nmid$ (`$\mid$` and `$\nmid$`) if that is what you meant.

Comment: `then a^2 = k^2 b^2` No, you got that backwards. It should rather be $b^2 = k^2 a^2\,$, so $3 b^2 = 3 k^2 a^2\,$. Or just use the transitivity of the relation $a^2 \mid b^2 \mid 3 b^2$.

Comment: it is $a \mid b \cdot a \mid b \cdot 1 \mid 3 \Rightarrow a^2 \mid 3b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have $a^2|b^2$ you can use the transitivity of divides by.  You have $b^2|3b^2$ so $a^2|3b^2$

Answer (score 1):

The converse case is interesting, though.

> Problem: If $a^2\mid 3b^2$ then $a\mid b$.

$a^2\mid 3b^2\Rightarrow a^2= 3kb^2\Rightarrow 3\mid a^2$ since if $3\nmid a$, then $a^2\equiv 1(\mod 3)$, by Fermat's theorem.

Now, $3\mid a^2\Rightarrow 9\mid a^2\Rightarrow 3\mid kb^2\Rightarrow 3\mid k\space\text{or}\space 3\mid b^2$

> Case 1: $3\mid b^2$

$3\mid b^2\Rightarrow 9\mid b^2\Rightarrow 3\mid \frac{a^2}{9}\Rightarrow 9\mid (\frac{a}{3})^2\Rightarrow 3\mid (\frac{b}{3})^2\Rightarrow \dots$

This implies $a$ and $b$ only multiple of $3$, and $a\mid b$

> Case 2: $3\mid k$

$3\mid k\Rightarrow k=3k_1\Rightarrow a^2=9k_1b^2$. Hence $k_1$ is a square integer, say $k_1=k^2_2$. Then $a^2=9k^2_2b^2\Rightarrow a=3k_2b\space \text{or}\space -3k_2b $. Hence, $a\mid b$.